# Microsoft Access cannot open database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

So I have this program which is given to me by my co-worker and I don't have any idea on how to use MS Access 2013, he gave 2 files. The first one is named as **SDBM-MAIN** and the second one is in the sub-folder named **SDBM-DATABASE**.

so when I open the the **SDBM-MAIN**, I see a dialog box and a button to start but when I click the start button, it gives me an error like this : Could not find file: `E:\Database Sample\blah blah blah . accdb`

and when I open the other file I get an `tables` and `queries`.

This is the first time to use MS Access any help will appreciated. Thanks

Comment: frankly u won't find someone explaining from scratch how to use ms access here. i suggest try google it, there are plenty of free learning resources for ms access.

Comment: To help you a bit, I think you need to relink the tables from SDBM-MAIN to SDBM-DATABASE

Answer (score 0):

Probably a code that try to retrieve tables from another external Access file.

Open **SDBM-MAIN**, press ALT+F11 and check in modules if there is something like a getPath function or a constant string called `dbPath` or something like that. Then update it to the new location of your **SDBM-DATABASE** file on your HDD.

Answer (score 0):

The two files are probably front end and back end. If you place the `SDBM-DATABASE` to where `SDBM-MAIN` is looking for it (that would be the `E:\Database Sample\blah blah blah . accdb`) it should work.